# how to contact lost phone5 if in low battery

Tags: iphone

I lost my iphone5 yesterday, and I already activated lost mode from my mac. Also, I believe find My iPhone is on on my iPhone. Question is, what if the phone gets low battery, will I still be able to locate my iPhone once it is online? I called the phone just this morning, but its not ringing anymore. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if it is not powered (to low battery), the find my phone wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Log into https://www.icloud.com/ using your AppleId and password.  If you have FindMyIPhone you will see an icon there, you should be able to at least see the phones last location before the battery died.  Unfortunately if the battery is dead the chime feature won't help much but if the phone is simply misplaced and not stolen this may still help you find it.